# no shipping costs added to product

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order

1. I created a simple product without variants (without possibility choosing sizes).

   - when this product is added to the basket, the system correctly adds the set delivery costs.
2. I created second configurable product with variants (need to choose the size of the product (S,M,L, or XL).

   - when I choose eg size M and add the product to the basket then then delivery costs are not added to the product. I can finalize the order without paying the shipping costs. How to solve it ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate **weight** attribute for simple products, as Magento2 will understand products with no weight are virtual, so with no shipping costs

More info https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4533

Comment: Raul, I set the weight of the product and everything works. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome, Sylvester